# How to hide selected link box

Tags: html, hyperlink

Not sure about all browsers, but I know in IE if you click on a link and hold, the link gets a dotted box around it.  Is there any way to stop that from happening?  it's ugly on my site.

Comment: If I guessed right, you *might* be looking for `a:active` selector?

Comment: @JCOC611 - I tried a:active, with a border set to none. No dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually something you shouldn't remove as it is a accessibility feature but if you must:

http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Removing-Dotted-Border-on-Clicked-Links

Answer (score 0):

That border you're seeing is actually the [outline](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#outline1) (or the [CSS2 version](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#dynamic-outlines)) so set `outline: none;` in your CSS. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zLaq5/

However, as Stofke notes, you should probably just leave it alone as it is an accessibility **feature**.